# Integrating Jetty with JAX-RS-Jersey

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, jersey, jax-rs

After an exhaustive search of the web and Stackoverflow, I am still stuck with trying to figure out how to integrate a RESTlet style interface provided by Jersey with Jetty.

I have my Jetty server up and running and as such Jersey seems pretty easy to use as well, does anyone know how to tie the two together? Any concrete links would help — I am a little new to servlet programming as well.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I created an app using Jetty and Jersey a while back. It's just a standard webapp really:

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest.service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>your.package.with.jersey.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest.service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

A rest resource:

```
package your.package.with.jersey.resources;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;

@Path("login")
public class LoginResource {

    @Context
    private SecurityContext security;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String login() {

        String email = security.getUserPrincipal().getName();
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

Jetty starter:

```
public class StartJetty {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Server server = new Server();
        SocketConnector connector = new SocketConnector();
        // Set some timeout options to make debugging easier.
        connector.setMaxIdleTime(1000 * 60 * 60);
        connector.setSoLingerTime(-1);
        connector.setPort(8080);
        server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });

        WebAppContext bb = new WebAppContext();
        bb.setServer(server);
        bb.setContextPath("/");
        bb.setWar("src/main/webapp");

        server.addHandler(bb);

        try {
            System.out.println(">>> STARTING EMBEDDED JETTY SERVER, PRESS ANY KEY TO STOP");
            server.start();
            while (System.in.available() == 0) {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            server.stop();
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(100);
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<!-- Jetty -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-management</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Jersey (JAX-RS) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.grizzly</groupId>
    <artifactId>grizzly-servlet-webserver</artifactId>
</dependency>

(...)

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>     
</plugin>
```

Hope these snippets point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less what I was looking for - although I abstracted some of the .xml stuff into the Java code - makes me work with one less thing!

Comment: you will also need ContextLoaderListener in web.xml and applicationContext.xml in web-inf

Comment: Why do you have a dependency to grizzly in there?

Comment: @Staineart good question. Either of two options: 1) I found out it worked when adding this dependency for some reason I have forgotten 2) I copy pasted dependencies and did not bother to check each one. If you find out it works fine without grizzly please let us know.

Comment: Thanks. @pk11 do you mind sharing what you have extracted from the web.xml into java I am curious to see because currently my server does not load the jersey resource and I cannot find why except that the web.xml is not loaded properly. I would rather to this with java it would be easier to port.

Answer (score 16):

You might want to look at [Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io) for out-of-the-box integration between Jetty, Jersey, Jackson, Logback/Log4j/JUL/CJL and JDBI, all nicely instrumented with Yammer Metrics.