# NoClassDefFoundError running simple rest app on jetty

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, jax-rs

I have an error trying to run simple JAX-RS example.
I'am using jaxrs-ri-2.4.1, and Jetty embedded server with "Run Jetty" plugin for eclipse.
Thank you.

```
web.xml
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>restServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
       <param-value>path_to_class.FormsRestService</param-value>
   </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>restServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

FormsRestService.java
package path_to_class;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/") 
public class FormsRestService {
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getStringHello(){
    return "Hello Jersey!";
}
}
```

And exception briefly (or full text here http://pastebin.com/fFMb7Y2a)

```
Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/server/ContainerException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
......
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I'moved to jetty 7, now I have such exception: pastebin.com/ZdRXzeED

Comment: It appears you are missing the Glassfish JARs.  I would start there.

Comment: Upgrade your Jetty version. `org.mortbay.jetty` is for Jetty 6 and earlier.  It is 4 years and over 100 stable releases out of date.

Comment: Joakim Erdfelt, I'moved to jetty 7, now I have such exception: http://pastebin.com/ZdRXzeED

Comment: CodeChimp, I use jaxrs-ri-2.4.1 and jersey-server.jar with org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException is loaded at startup according to the jetty log. Should I use something else?

Answer (score 0):

`jaxrs-ri-2.4.1` expects that you run on Glassfish.

Look at this old question (and **both** answers) for some help.

[Integrating Jetty with JAX-RS-Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048004/integrating-jetty-with-jax-rs-jersey)