# jax-rs and server name

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs

I am still working on a jax-rs server, and I faced some new problems recently. I do not understand where I define the name of my webserver. I searched everything in my workspace, but couldn't find anything.
Let's roll out the problem a bit further:

I always reach my server's @GET method via `http://XXXXXX.XXXXX.XXX-XXXXXXX.de/android/`

This is the structure of my server class:

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserResource {

Connection dbconn = null;

public UserResource() {
    userIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    userIds.add(1);
    userIds.add(2);
    userIds.add(3);
}

@GET
@Path("/login/{id}")
@Consumes("application/xml")
public StreamingOutput getTests(@PathParam("id") int id, InputStream is) {
    return new StreamingOutput() {
        public void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException,
                WebApplicationException {
            getTests(outputStream);
        }
    };
}
```

As you see, the path of my class is "/users", and the path of the @GET method is "/login/1" (for example id = 1). Now I tried to call the method via

```
http://XXXXXX.XXXXX.XXX-XXXXXXX.de/android/users/login/1
```

But this does not work. I get an error (unknown source). And my error.log says that it couldn't find the resource at

```
http://XXXXXX.XXXXX.XXX-XXXXXXX.de/users/users/login/1
```

My 1st question: Where does the double "/users" come from? I have no idea. When I leave away the "/users" in my request url, there will be only 1 "/users" in the error.log, but still the resource is not found.

And there is another thing I did not find out yet: How do I change the name of my service? Atm, it's "android", but how could I change this? I searched my whole workspace, found "android" in my pom.xml, but when i change it to, let's say "testandroid", upload everything, build and run the server, the name is still android. No idea why this is the case.

Thx for your help guys!

EDIT:
This is my "main" class:

```
package com.restfully.services;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class ServerApplication extends Application {
   private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
   private Set<Class<?>> empty = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

   public ServerApplication() {
      singletons.add(new UserResource());
   }

   @Override
   public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
      return empty;
   }

   @Override
   public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
      return singletons;
   }
}
```

I am using Eclipse and Maven. The application runs on a jetty-server. If you could use any further information, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look in the following places

Pom.xml file for context root the following entry;

```
<configuration>
    <context>yourWarName</context>
</configuration>
```

Using Netbeans check Run Category context path under project properties.

```
Context Path: /yourWarName
```

Have a look in your `web.xml` as well.

When using jax-rs you normally define a config class;

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class RestConfig extends Application{

}
```

From there you define your other paths;

```
    @Stateless
    @Path("/login")
    public class LoginResource

    public Response login(Credentials credentials) {
    Credentials result = this.loginService.login(credentials);
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(result).build();
     }
```

The path to the following is: http://domain.com/MyApp/resources/login
where MyApp is the context root.

It might be that there is a path specified in config or root with the name users that you are getting the double users.

Comment: Thx for your help man!

But still I do not understand where the 2 "/users" come from in my error.log

Comment: Can you maybe supply more info, your environment and configuration. It is difficult to see what may cause the error by only having the `UserResource` class visible.

Comment: Also check after the build in the packaged file (myApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war) the path name in the context.xml file under your META-INF folder.

Comment: Are you doing any config in your web.xml or context.xml files?

Comment: I do not have a context.xml file :-/

Comment: I see you are running the project on jetty. I'm running all my projects on Tomee. Haven't done any hosting on Jetty but have a look on how you setup the jetty server for Rest, [Integrating Jetty with JAX-RS-Jersey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048004/integrating-jetty-with-jax-rs-jersey).